# Is $T$, the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is $T$, the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, countable?

Here is my attempt at a proof:

Let $S$ = {$ (a_0, a_1, ..., a_k)$ | $a_i\in \Bbb Z$, $k \in \Bbb N$}

$T$ is the set in question. That is, $T$ = {$ (a_0, a_1x, ..., a_kx^{k})$ | $a_i \in \Bbb Z$, $k \in \Bbb N$}.

Then by the enumeration principle $S$ is countable, i.e., |$S$| = |$\Bbb N$|, because it can be labelled by

$L =$ {$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, , , (, )$} [Note: I've included "," as an element].

Now define an injection $f: T \to S$ by:

$f(a_0 + a_1x + ... +a_kx^{k}$) = ($a_0, a_1, ..., a_k$).

Then $|T| \le |S|$.

We can define a similar injection $g: S \to T$, establishing |$S| \le |T$|. So |$T$| = |$S$| = |$\Bbb N$| which is what we wanted to prove.

Is this good? I'm pretty new to set theory so I want to make sure these proofs are valid.

Comment: Set membership is denoted by $\in$, not E.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any polynomial $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Z$ can be written as $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots +a_nx^n,n\in \Bbb N$.

Since $a_i\in \Bbb Z$ ,and $\Bbb Z$ is countable so for each $a_i$ we have countable choices .

**EDIT**:By "choices" I mean number of options available for us to select the $a_i's$ from.Since the polynomial is over $\Bbb Z$ so we have the option of selecting the $a_i's$ from the set of integers.

And since countable union of countable sets is countable so the set of all polynomials over $\Bbb Z$ is countable also

Comment: I did not get that ;@RSerrao; Also why the downvote;It's hard to understand your comment

Comment: i don't understand the comment of @RSerrao either; i believe this answer is correct (the set in question is most definitely countable)

Comment: And the funnier part is that he has downvoted the other answers so irresponsibly

Comment: no good deed goes unpunished, lol

Comment: can someone explain what "choices" means here?

Comment: I have added an edit for your convenience.Check it @WilsonBrians

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are on the right track. I don't think you have to make such a long argument that $|S| = |T|$ ... you can just say that each $S$-member is uniquely determined by a choice of $k$ and of $a_i$ with $i \leq k$, and likewise for each $T$-member, so there is a clear bijection between $S$ and $T$, so $|S| = |T|$.

But as someone else just noted in an answer, you need to construct a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $S$ (or $T$). I would do something like this: starting at stage 0, enumerate the polynomials with $k \leq 0$ and $|a_i| \leq 0$ for each $i \leq k$; then, at stage 1, enumerate those polynomials with $k \leq 1$ and $|a_i| \leq 1$ for each $i \leq k$ (that have not been already listed), and so on for each stage $> 1$. (That is, at stage $n$, "tack on" to your enumeration all polynomials that were not previously listed and that have $k \leq n$ and the absolute value of each $a_i$ less than or equal to $n$). At each stage you add only finitely many polynomials to your enumeration, and every polynomial gets listed at some stage, so there are only countably many.

Answer (score -1):

Send (a_0,a_1x^1,...a_nx^n) to (p_0^(a_0),p_1^(a_1),....) where p_i is the i+1th prime.

Answer (score -2):

Your result only holds if you show that $|S| = |\Bbb N|$ which you have not done because you could not use the enumeration principle. $S$ has infinitely many elements of the form $(a, 0, \cdots, 0) $ and then infinitely many terms of the form $(0, b, 0, \cdots) $ and then infinitely many of the form $(a, b, 0, \cdots) $ and so on and so forth and therefore you cannot enumerate them with that ease. That is the problem with the demonstration. You would still have to build an explicit injection from $S $ on to $\Bbb N $ to prove $|S| = |\Bbb N|$.

Comment: Excuse me, but if you try to apply Cantor's diagonalization here, as you said, you get a "polynomial" that eventually looks like $\ldots+x^N+x^{N+1}+x^{N+2}+\ldots$.  This is not a polynomial.  In fact, learnmore is correct, and it is countable.

Comment: @BobJones then the argument fails somewhere in non-trivial way. The answer is now as it was when it was first accepted. I will read more on countability and uncountability.

Comment: There is an enumeration.  We take an enumeration from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq0}$, then to sequences of nonnegative integers that eventually reach $0$ by taking the rational's continued fraction expansion and subtracting 1 from all except the first term, then to sequences of integers that eventually reach $0$, by taking a bijection from $\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ sending $0$ to $0$.  There is an obvious bijection from these to polynomials.

Comment: I still really don't see what the difference between your objection to my use of the enumeration principle here and the way the enumeration principle is used to prove the countability of the rationals. If I understand what you're saying, my argument doesn't work because, for instance, we can generate infinitely many sequences of the form, say $(0, 9, 0, ... 0)$ where every entry is $0$ except the second entry which begins with the digit $9$. Or whatever. But aren't there rationals like this too? E.g., infinitely many rationals generated by $\frac{5}{9}$ where we keep adding $9$'s to denom.

Comment: @WilsonBrians yes there are. but you said "Then by the enumeration principle S is countable, i.e., |S| = |N|, because it can be labelled by L={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,,(,)}" which is equivalent to saying "by the enumeration principle |Q| = |N|. You just invoked the principle, you didn't prove it could be used. The enumeration principle states that if you can enumerate a set, then it has the same cardinality as N. You did not show S was enumerable. You just said it was.

Comment: @RSerrao What? I didn't just invoke it... The enumeration principle says that every set that can be labeled by a countable set is countable. Here I thought my "labelling" set was $L$. Since I thought $\Bbb Z$ could be labelled by $L$, I thought I could use the enumeration principle to prove $\Bbb Z$ was countable...

Comment: @RSerrao If you mean that I didn't explain how the labelling would occur, that's true, but only because I thought it was obvious. To each element in the sequence of each $S_i$, write the integer representation from the list $L$ separated by a comma.